# XML serialization: 64Bit Windows7, oct processor cored, 32GB RAM and OutOfMemory exception

Tags: c#, string, windows-7, xml-serialization, out-of-memory

While processing `500 MB` data and trying to serialize it,

```
GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)
```

throws `System.OutOfMemoryException`

**XML Serializer:**

```
StringWriter xmlStr = new StringWriter();

XmlTextWriter twa = new XmlTextWriter(xmlStr);

lock(myLock)
{
    mySerializer.WriteObject(twa, myHandlerMap); // OutOfMemoryException

    twa.Flush();
    twa.Close();

    set.StringBuffer = xmlStr.ToString();

    xmlStr.Dispose()
}
```

After reading the last paragraph at following link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/10/10/stringbuilder-outofmemoryexception.aspx

I doubt if it is possible to solve this issue without MS fixing it?

**Exception Trace:**

```
RemoteStackTrace:    
   at System.String.GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.GetNewString(String currentString, Int32 requiredLength)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char value)
   at System.IO.StringWriter.Write(Char value)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.InternalWriteEndElement(Boolean longFormat)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.WriteString(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, String value, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns)
   at WriteKeyValueOfstringstringToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at WriteArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerializeWithSurrogate(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteGenericViewingMPStateToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerializeWithSurrogate(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteSerializationInfo(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Type objType, SerializationInfo serInfo)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteISerializable(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, ISerializable obj)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerializeWithSurrogate(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteKeyValueOfstringStateSerializeSetjJgp3TWnToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at WriteArrayOfKeyValueOfstringStateSerializeSetjJgp3TWnToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)
```

Pls. let me know how can it be solved?

Comment: they say that this is unlikely to happen on x64 machines, are you 100% sure your application is running in 64 bit mode? if this is a client/server app, are both components running on x64 machines?

Comment: Have you verified that the culprit is the LOH? Some managed memory profilers are able to show you how the LOH is used. Have you tried running in 64 bit? 500 MB of data is a lot if you also want to have a serialized copy in memory simultaneously. A 32 bit process have access to 2 GB of virtual memory. The remaining 2 GB is used by Windows.

Comment: Provide more code how you serialize....Otherwise consider to write your own custom serializer even for XML.

Comment: @DavidePiras: yes, server is 64 bit. client is sometimes 32bit.

Comment: @Martin: Tried `Perfmon` and process & memory performance counters are fine.

Comment: If you know the upper cap on the file size, have you tried creating the `StringBuilder` with enough capacity from the outset?

Comment: Till 60 MB it serializes correctly.

Comment: "without MS fixing it?" makes it sound like purely an MS issue... but ultimately, you are trying to create a huge xml string in memory. This is not trivial, and arguably the real thing that needs fixing is: your design on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

500MB is pretty big for xml, and it would not surprise me to hear that it isn't happy. If possible, I would look at something *streaming*-based, i.e. `XmlWriter`/`XmlReader`. Without more detail it isn't clear whether that is possible here. Alternatively, consider another format! Seriously... xml doesn't play nicely at big sizes.

The first thing to try, though, is... *don't use a string* (or StringBuilder); but instead, read/write directly from/to disk via a `FileStream` over an `XmlReader`/`XmlWriter`.

Comment: Pls. see the code added. it's the API provided and i've to use that only. Can't write my own method to read/write directly from/to disk. :-(

Comment: @Azodious why not? why do you need to use a `StringBuilder` here?

Comment: it's API provided by another library and data should be serialized at specific location (known to that lib only).

Comment: Garvell : Please refer the exception.

Comment: @Azodious it blew up extending the string... yes, that is entirely what I would have expected... and?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer serializing this directly into a file. 500 MB is a quite a huge data and will getting much more when serializing it in "chatty" xml.